# How can I tell Smart Map to look at Commerce for entries?

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I have Smart Map working perfectly *within* Commerce. Meaning, I am able to show a map, etc. when I'm looking at products.

However, I am trying to build a "product locator" to find products in my area.

I am able to successfully pass the arguments to my results page - I can print out the zip code and distance that was chosen, but I am always getting into my "no results found" case.

```
{% set target = craft.request.getParam('near') %}
{% set radius = (craft.request.getParam('radius')) craft.request.getParam('radius') : 200 %}
    {% set params = {
    'target': target,
    'range': radius
} %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.address(params).order('distance').find() %}
```

`radius` is a drop-down of (miles) to choose from. 
`near` is the name of the text input the user enters the zip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Craft to look within the Commerce section like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.commerce.products.address(params).order('distance').find() %}
```